# Java regex capture EOL, regex over stream

Tags: java, regex, eol

I'm trying to implement regex over stream (Reader). I'm using the following approach:

1. Read N chars to buffer
2. Call matcher.find() on this buffer
3. Trim from the beginning till matcher.end() position and append buffer to N chars length
4. Loop

There is an issue with regex ^(.*)$ (it is user data and it is not possible to change it). The matcher did not capture line endings, so matcher.end() returns last symbol before \n char not the \n itself. And after that program loops in empty string. E.g. we have input "ABC\nCDE"

- matcher captures ABC and matcher.end() returns 2
- substring(2) returns "\nCDE"
- matcher captures empty string and loops here

Is there is any way to make mather include EOL chars into capturing group? Or there is regex implementations for Java that work with streams?

P.S. There is one solution but it is very ugly, I do not wont to implement it:

```
String text = "ABC\r\nDEF\r\nGHI\r\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
boolean first = true;
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find(first ? 0 : 1)) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    text = text.substring(matcher.end() - 1);
    matcher.reset(text);
    first = false;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `BufferedReader` with its `readLine()` method?

Comment: It looks to me like you should be using `DOTALL` mode instead of `MULTILINE` mode; that's the one that lets the dot match newlines.  Also, are you familiar with the `java.util.Scanner` class?  Applying regexes to streams is at the core of its functionality.

Comment: Use something like `(?s)\A.*\z` which is unambiguous.

Comment: Because this is universal code that parse input using provided regex. Not all of them include EOL boundaries. As I already mentioned I could not change regex, and did not know what regex user will use.